# Bootstrap 4 nav-tabs dropdown-items not toggling through active tabpanels

Tags: html, bootstrap-4

When I use nav-tabs to switch between tabpanels, it works fine, but it does not change the active tabpanel when I try to switch it using the links in the dropdown menu. My HTML for the nav-tabs and dropdown menu is below, as well as a code snippet, if anybody can look at it and help.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" dir="ltr">

<head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">
</head>

<body>
  <div>
    <ul class="nav nav-tabs nav-justified">
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link active" data-toggle="tab" href="#tab1">tab1</a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" data-toggle="tab" href="#tab2">tab2</a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" data-toggle="tab" href="#tab3">tab3</a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item dropdown">
        <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" href="#" role="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">tabs</a>
        <div class="dropdown-menu dropdown-menu-center">
          <a class="dropdown-item" href="#tab1">tab1</a>
          <a class="dropdown-item" href="#tab2">tab2</a>
          <a class="dropdown-item" href="#tab3">tab3</a>
        </div>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
  <div class="tab-content">
    <div role="tabpanel" class="tab-pane container fade show active" id="tab1">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-xl-8 col-lg-8 col-md-8 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">
          <h3>tab1</h3>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div role="tabpanel" class="tab-pane container fade" id="tab2">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-xl-8 col-lg-8 col-md-8 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">
          <h3>tab2</h3>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div role="tabpanel" class="tab-pane container fade" id="tab3">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-xl-8 col-lg-8 col-md-8 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">
          <h3>tab3</h3>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-KJ3o2DKtIkvYIK3UENzmM7KCkRr/rE9/Qpg6aAZGJwFDMVNA/GpGFF93hXpG5KkN" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.9/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ApNbgh9B+Y1QKtv3Rn7W3mgPxhU9K/ScQsAP7hUibX39j7fakFPskvXusvfa0b4Q" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JZR6Spejh4U02d8jOt6vLEHfe/JQGiRRSQQxSfFWpi1MquVdAyjUar5+76PVCmYl" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</body>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Put the `data-toggle="tab"` on the links inside of the drop down and it should work. :)